# using Rstudio, how to import xlsx file larger than 100MB?

Tags: r, shiny, readxl

How to work with excel file larger than 100 MB, I already imported but it doesn't running the shiny app?

Comment: What did you use to import and under what conditions? What do you mean by "doesn't running the shiny app"?

Comment: if you use `fileInput`, try this one  `options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 120 * 1024^2)`

Comment: @jyjek i m not familiar with your suggestion, the file size is 129 MB format CSV

Answer (score 1):

if the excel is format ,you can save as csv .then you can use`data.table::fread()` to read. it's more effective and easily , csv  is ligthter than xlsx

Comment: it doesn't work too